# Power series of $f(x)=\frac{7}{8-x}+\frac{8}{x-9}$ at $x=0$ and radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, power-series

> Find the power series representation of $f(x)=\frac{7}{8-x}+\frac{8}{x-9}$ at $x=0$

I know how to find them separately, but not together.

$$\frac{7}{8-x} = \frac{7}{8}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{8}} = \frac{7}{8}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{x}{8}\right)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{7 x^n}{8^{n+1}}$$

and the same concept applied to the other one gives:
$$\frac{8}{x-9} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty-\frac{8x^n}{9^{n+1}}$$

And $R$ for the first would be $8$ and $R$ for the second would be $9$.

But I'm lost on how to find them when they are added together in the same function.

Comment: what about adding the power series?

Comment: To determine the radius of convergence: If you have a series which is the sum of two series, one which converge and one which diverge then the sum also diverge.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the power series, may be you could write that $$\frac{7}{8-x}+\frac{8}{x-9}=\frac{x-1}{(x-9) (x-8)}=-\frac{1-x}{72-17 x+x^2}=-\frac 1{72}\frac{1-x}{1-\frac{17 x-x^2}{72}}$$ and  consider that $$\frac 1 {1-y}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n$$ Replace $y$ by $\frac{17 x-x^2}{72}$ and use the binomial theorem $$\frac{1}{1-\frac{17 x-x^2}{72}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{17 x-x^2}{72}\right)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{17 -x}{72}\right)^nx^n$$and, when done, multiply the result by $-\frac{1-x}{72}$.

Another solution could be tor write $$\frac{7}{8-x}+\frac{8}{x-9}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_i x^i$$ that is to say $$x-1=(72-17 x+x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_i x^i$$ and compare coefficients for the same power of $x$. Looking at the very first terms, you have $$-1=72a_0$$ $$1=17a_0+72a_1$$ that is to say $$a_0=-\frac 1{72}\qquad , \qquad a_1=\frac {55}{72^2}$$ All the other terms (which do not appear in the left hand side) satisfy the recurrence relation $$a_{n-2}-17a_{n-1}+72 a_n=0$$ to which correspond $$a_n=c_1 9^{-n}+c_2 8^{-n}$$ Using as initial conditions $$a_1=\frac {55}{72^2}\qquad , \qquad a_2=\frac {1007}{72^3}$$ this should lead to $$a_n=\frac{7\times 9^{n+1}-8^{n+1}}{72^{n+1}}$$ from which $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=???$$ and then the radius of convergence looking at the limit of this last ratio when $n\to \infty$.